# Synchronization Kindle between Macbook Pro and tablet

Tags: kindle, sync

I want to read and edit books and pdfs on all my devices(Macbook Pro, Ipad Pro and Samsung Galaxy A7). I tried Kindle for this. However, Kindle for mac is not compatible with others. When I use sendToKindle to sync my new books, I can send only IPad and Samsung not to Mac. How can I sync and edit all my documents on Kindle? My Mac is does not have M1 chip so I can't download the app from App Store. Are there other apps for my requirements? Thanks in advance.